# Hive - copy values from previous rows

Tags: null, hive, copy, records, multiple-records

I'm trying to write a Hive query that will copy the value of a field from the previous row in the same column, if the value in the current field is NULL. If the current value is not null, it should be retained. For example, if I have the following input:

```
    company    empId   first_name   last_ame    job_code   department   start_date
    110        500400   ABC          XYZ         300        101         01/20/2015
    110        500400   Null         Null        305        105         04/02/2015
    110        500400   ABC1         Null        Null       Null        15/02/1015
    110        500400   Null         XYZ1        307        Null        01/03/2015
```

The output should be something like this:

```
    company    empId   first_name   last_name   job_code   department   start_date
    110        500400   ABC          XYZ         300        101         01/20/2015
    110        500400   ABC          XYZ         305        105         04/02/2015
    110        500400   ABC1         XYZ         305        105         15/02/1015
    110        500400   ABC1         XYZ1        307        105         01/03/2015
```

I tried queries using both last_value and lag functions and both don't seem to be working. With last_value, it is only working when there are a limited number of rows. When I run it on a large data set, it fails (map-red does not complete). This the query I am trying:

```
    select
    company, empId, start_date,
    last_value(last_name, true) over (partition by company, empId order by    start_date) as last_name,
    last_value(first_name, true) over (partition by company, empId order by start_date) as first_name,
    last_value(department, true) over (partition by company, empId order by start_date) as department,
    last_value(job_code, true) over(partition by company,empId order by start_date) as job_code from samples.z_sample_test order by start_date;
```

With lag, only one record is getting updated. All subsequent records are not getting updated. This is the query I am using:

```
    select
    c.company,
    c.empId,
    c.start_date,
    if(c.first_name is null, lag(c.first_name, 1) over (order by c.start_date), c.first_name) as first_name,
    if(c.last_name is null, lag(c.last_name, 1) over (order by    c.start_date), c.last_name) as last_name,
    if(c.job_code is null, lag(c.job_code, 1) over (order by c.start_date), c.job_code) as job_code,
    if(c.department is null, lag(c.department, 1) over (order by c.start_date), c.department) as department
    from samples.z_sample_test c
    left join samples.z_sample_test p
    on (c.company = p.company and c.empId = p.empId)
    group by c.company, c.employee, c.start_date, c.last_name, c.first_name,  c.job_code, c.department order by c.start_date;
```

I appreciate any help in this matter.

Comment: please edit your question to include an example of the query you are trying

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response....Please find the code attached. I am using Lag in the above query

Comment: Added both the queries.